# renaming attributes - Cloudera

Tags: sql, cloudera

I have a variable `call_15_second` that has the values: 0, 1, Null
Hence I firstly take care of the NULLs and change them into 0 which the code below should do.

```
sum(COALESCE(call_15_second, 0)) AS    call_15_second,
```

At the same time, I actually want to change all '1' values/ attributes into either '15' (numeric - so I potentially could do further calculations) - or '15secs' (character value) 
How can I do that om Cloudera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for anybody who needs it too:

```
SELECT CASE call_15_second
WHEN   1 then   15
ELSE   0 
END
AS call_15_second
FROM old ;
```